# Does $f(z)$ exist such that $f'$ and $f''$ exist in $\mathbb{C}$ but $f'''$ does not?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible to find $f(z)$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f'$ and $f''$ exist everywhere on $\mathbb{C}$ but $f'''$ does not?

I'm guessing no such $f(z)$ exists, but I don't know how to prove this. What I've done so far:

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

If $f'$ exists on $\mathbb{C}$ then $f(z)$ is analytic and the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$:

$u_x=v_y$  and $u_y=-v_x$

Similarly $f''$ exists on $\mathbb{C}$ so $\Delta u=0$ and $\Delta v=0$ .

I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: You have basically stated that if $f$ is analytic, then also $f'$ is (which is true). So you can go on to $f''$, $f'''$ and so on *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such function exists.

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).

Convergent power series are infinitely differentiable in the interior of the disk of convergence.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.